# Replace setTimeout in useEffect when waiting for props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looking for a better solution to using `setTimeout` to wait for `props` using the `useEffect()` hook. Currently I have working as intended

```
const sessionCookie = getCookie('_session');
const { verifiedEmail } = props.credentials;
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
useEffect(() => {
  const timeoutLoading = setTimeout(() => setLoading(false), 2000);
  if (!loading) {
    if (sessionCookie) {
      if (verifiedEmail) {
        window.location.href = 'https://1.example.com';
      }
    } else {
      window.location.href = 'https://2.example.com';
    }
  }
  return () => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutLoading);
  };
}, [loading]);
```

whereas `props.credentials` in it's initial state is `{}`, awaiting a `response` from the server to give the value for `verifiedEmail` and `sessionCookie` relies on a function `getCookie` to return whether the cookie exists and the `value`.

Whilst this works, it's not ideal. One example would be in some user cases, 2s isn't enough time, in others it makes the user wait, when the props are already available.

My question is, how can I create a `promise` or use `async/await` to achieve the same affect without the risk of using `setTimeout`.

NOTE: `props.credentials` are not available on `render` and will always return an empty `object` before containing `verifiedEmail`. In some cases, the `sessionCookie` may not be available on `render` too but will also be available before `props.credentials` has `verifiedEmail`. If `sessionCookie` exists, `verifiedEmail` will too shortly after.

Ideally I would it best to create a `promise` around `getCookie`, then ensure the `_session` is available before identifying `verifiedEmail` exists. Any thoughts?

`getCookie()` is as below

```
const getCookie = (name: string) => {
  const v = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + name + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
  return v ? v[2] : null;
};
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the sessionCookie dependencies in the useEffect, as you know it will run the effect when there is a change in the cookie and you can maintain a loading state not based on setTimeout, bases on the cookie state.

Comment: i don't know if this is the right suggestion, but can you give it a shot? `props.credentials` is `{}` in the beginning, but after some time ( cookie refresh and all that ), it's value gets set, i.e., the `props` variable changed, which means a re-render has occured. Can you create a `useEffect` with `props.credentials` as it's dependency array? And check for any luck?

Comment: @SamridhTuladhar. Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, this cannot work. Being that `props.credentials` is rendered first as `{}` before the `sessionCookie` is available, therefore, the condition assumes there is no cookie and the user is redirected as such.

Comment: @PunithK. For that to work, the `sessionCookie` would need to be passed by a parent, of which there is none.

Comment: when you use setTimeout, does this mean credentials will be fetched by ajax so this props is not available at the first rendering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

Can you add a new prop called `hasAuthenticated` or something like that. While your request is pending, this can be false. Once the request is complete, set it to true and apply your logic at that time, just like `isLoading`.

That should remove the need for timers.

**Previous**

You could try something like this using two `useEffects`. First one will handle setting your session cookie and the second one will trigger the window change.

I'm not sure how your `getCookie` function works though.

```
const [sessionCookie, setSessionCookie] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
const { verifiedEmail } = props.credentials;

useEffect(() => {
    const getSession = async () => {
        setSessionCookie(await getCookie('_session'));
        setLoading(false);
    }
    getSession();
}, [setSessionCookie, getCookie, setLoading]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (!loading) {
        if (sessionCookie) {
            if (verifiedEmail) {
                window.location.href = 'https://1.example.com';
            }
        } else {
            window.location.href = 'https://2.example.com';
        }
    }
}, [sessionCookie, verifiedEmail, loading]);
```

Comment: Thank you Todd. I will add `getCookie` to the question. Unfortunately, await has no effect on `getCookie`.

Comment: Why does getCookie not have a value sometimes and requires you to wait? Are you setting the cookie somewhere else in the project? You'll need to inform your component that the cookie has or hasn't been set in some form. I'm guessing you are trying to distinguish between "not yet" authenticated and not authenticated.

Comment: Yes, the cookie is added upon the user reaching this page. However, the code above is wrapping the page at the top level, meaning that at render, sessionCookie is not available. There is a reason for this that would complicate the question. I can get around this by removing getCookie and only listening to credentials but for security, verifying the cookie and credentials is more ideal. Exactly, "not yet" and "not" is exactly what I need to achieve.

Comment: Can you add a new prop called `hasAuthenticated` or something like that. While your request is pending, this can be false. Once the request is complete, set it to true and apply your logic at that time, just like `isLoading`.

Comment: Thank you Todd. That is basically what I ended up doing. I have an object called `authenticated` that is initially null. If session cookie is available and credentials object.key.length is > 1, they are shown as boolean's in the `authenticated` object. If you wanted to update your question to be your comment above, I'd happily accept as answer. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out.